# Inherit Viewcontroller in Swift when creating new files

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ide

I Have created a custom Base Class in my Swift project that I would like to inherit in all the viewcontrollers I used in the app. The problem i see is in Objective-C when we create a new files it gives suggestions if you have created any custom class of yours and would like to inherit from them but in swift it didn't gave me any suggestion i have to create a class by extending  provided classes and then have to manually replace the extended class to my view controller.

Objective-c project

[image]

**Qestion : why it is not giving me suggestion to subclass from the class that i've created in my project. is this feature is available in swift or not? or is there anything I miss?**

> Note: I had developed applications in Objective-C and this is the first time i'm using swift.

Comment: Is your app have swift-objc bridge? If yes, you need to add your baseviewcontroller to Bridge Header

Comment: Xcode UI aside, what does the compiler say if you just create the class yourself? You don't need a wizard to create a class.

Comment: No its pure swift based. @U.Benlice

Comment: Agreed! but the whole point of asking the question is how it is working in objective-c and not in swift.

Comment: using manually entered name not giving error.<don't write .swift extension while entering manually>

Comment: did you try that with a custom class you've created? @Jack

Comment: @dreamBegin Yes.

Comment: its strange, its working for me too now? i didn''t added the extention name maybe that was a Case issue? and it also add a suffix of the type of class! @Jack

Comment: @dreamBegin yes that was issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type manually subclass name without extension. (No .swift)

OR

```
class SSTableViewCell: ExpandingTableViewCell
```

where `SSTableViewCell` is your class & `ExpandingTableViewCell` is parent

Answer (score 0):

You can just write your class name in the `Subclass of:` field, it doesn't matter if you get autocomplete there or not. Or you can just leave the subclass of set to `UIViewController` and then when file is created change from:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
```

to

```
class ViewController: YourBaseClassViewController
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion mate! but that i already mentioned in the question.

Comment: It actually matters if you get autocomplete. If you don't you should check if perhaps the swift file has no target (to the current one you're trying to do).